# Intersection of Circle and Parabola

Tags: circles, conic-sections, coordinate-systems

Q) Suppose the circle with equation $x^{2} + y^{2} + 2fx + 2gy + c = 0$ cuts the parabola $y^{2} = 4ax,(a> 0)$ at four distinct points. If $d$ denotes the sum of the ordinates of these four points, then the set of possible values of $d$ is

(A) $\{ 0 \}$

(B) $(-4a,4a)$

(C) $(-a,a)$

(D) $(-\infty ,\infty )$

**My Approach :-** Since , the equation of circle is $x^{2} + y^{2} + 2fx + 2gy + c = 0$ . I can write it as $(x-(-f))^{2} + (y-(-g))^{2} = \left ( \sqrt{f^{2}+ g^{2}-c} \right )^{2}$
So, center of this circle is $(-f,-g)$ and radius is $  \sqrt{f^{2}+ g^{2}-c} $. Now, I assumed $4$ distinct points where given circle and parabola are intersecting are $(x_{1},y_{1}),(x_{2},y_{2}),(x_{3},y_{3}),(x_{4},y_{4})$.
I have to find here $d=y_{1}+y_{2}+y_{3}+y_{4}.$
Now these above $4$ points should be at the same distance from the center of a circle which is equal to radius.
  So, $(y_{1}+g)^{2} + (x_{1}+f)^{2} = f^{2}+g^{2}-c$ and point $(x_{1},y_{1})$ satisfy the equation of given parabola also. So, $y_{1}^{2}=4ax_{1}$ (or) $x_{1}=\frac{y_{1}^{2}}{4a}$. So, equation becomes $(y_{1}+g)^{2} + (\frac{y_{1}^{2}}{4a}+f)^{2} = f^{2}+g^{2}-c$
Now,I stuck here because this equation contains terms like $y_{1}^{2}$, $y_{1}$, $y_{1}^{4}$. If I let $y_{1}^{2}=z$ then it also not help to easily solve this equation for the value of $y_{1}$.
I also tried to take some values of $a,f,g$ to eliminate options but got stuck again.
Please help me to tell the procedure to solve this question.

Comment: I have got a polynomial equation of degree four,depending on the parameters $$f,g,c$$. Here you must consider several cases for $$f,g,c,a$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**

You have$$x^{2} + y^{2} + 2fx + 2gy + c = 0\qquad \text{and} \qquad y^2=4ax$$

Replace $x$ by $\frac{y^2}{4a}$ to get
$$y^4+ 8a\left(2a+ f\right)\,y^2+32 a^2 g \,y+16 a^2 c=0$$

What is the sum of the roots ? No case to study !

Comment: Thank you. I didn't think this way.

Comment: @ankit. I am very lazy ! So ... Stay simple ! Cheers :-)

Comment: @ankit. Be more lazy : using $x=\frac {y^2}a$ there is no way to produce an $y^3$ term. End of the story !

Comment: haha.. nice (y)